# TCP: what happens on simultaneous send of peers?

Tags: tcp

Suppose that a server and client simultaneously execute `send()` — with my knowledge they're both would send a data, next both start waiting for an Ack message, which *nobody would send*.

But such a problem never appears, so what happens actually?

Comment: Thank you for asking.  Sadly the community voted this off topic; please ask on [so]

Comment: @MikePennington why, aren't the TCP protocol related to Networking? I'd say it is a foundation of networking.

Comment: how to use the send() kernel api is off topic.  as phrased the question is very ambiguous, of course network engineers mostly don't notice because they don't use these APIs. http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/429/775

Comment: @MikePennington is a bit careless☺ α) The send I mentioned isn't kernel API, the SEND is part of TCP rfc793, and β) The question is about protocol implementation, not how to use a send() function.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, the OPEN call mentioned in the RFC is programmatic and not a packet that is sent across the network. If you read section 2.7 starting on page 10, you'll see that the OPEN call is part of the protocol stack on a system. Even the language "call" indicates it's programmatic, contrasted with the word "segment" used at the end of section 2.7 to describe the PDU containing the SYN flag. If you replace "send()" in your question with "SYN", your question will be on-topic and the accepted answer will make more sense.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I am actually bad in TCP even though I have read the RFC. Just to be sure I understand: so, for the time of communication, a sequence of packets with data, that requiring an Ack after being send, should be preceded by Syn?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last question. If you want to understand TCP, reading the RFC is probably one of the hardest ways to do it. There must be tons of TCP primers online that will have it in simpler terms. And this site is not the place for a TCP primer.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I am just trying to understand why are you saying I ought to replace the `send()` with Syn; I didn't understood it from you previous comment. If the Syn ought to be sent before packets with data, either if Syn **is** a packet to carry a data — then it makes a sense.

Comment: Looked at this several times today trying to decide how to handle it.  What I keep thinking after reading through everything again is that the OP does not have a firm grasp on TCP operation and is not asking the question he is intending to ask, using what he thinks is the right terminology but missing the mark.  @Hi-Angel, I am going to put this on hold, but please edit the question to try to restate what you are really trying to get answered.

Comment: @MikePennington if you really think it's useless for future readers, I can delete the question. Shall I?

Comment: If you want to delete it, you'll have to flag for moderator attention.  You can't delete questions with upvoted answers without a mod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TCP is bidirectional.**  There are actually two halves of a pipe created between client and server; think of this as being a full-duplex operation in that both sides of the conversation can send and receive simultaneously.

But before any real communication can take place, the client needs to initiate a connection to the server first with a TCP SYNchronize (flag) packet and the server is expected to respond with a TCP SYN toward the client with a piggybacked ACK, and finally the client ACKs the server TCP SYN.  This is the **TCP SYN-SYN/ACK-ACK 3-way handshake.**   Packets are then free to flow in either direction until the connection is torn down.

Comment: I see, so there is like two different pipes, and, perhaps, different threads for reading and writing…

Comment: this answer demonstrates little understanding of the real issue in this question

Comment: @MikePennington no, it's okay. I was needed to implement an own protocol for some reason, and I wondered how is that done in TCP. I think the anwer answers it.

Comment: @Mike Pennington: This all seems fairly clear to me except I think the OP probably should have written "SYN packet" instead of "send() function". Looks like generalneteorkerror had the same thought, answered along those lines, and the answer was accepted. Maybe someone with edit powers could edit the original question?

Comment: @ToddWilcox the "send() function" is actually mentioned as interface in TCP rfc.

Comment: @todd, send() != syn.  If someone is silly enough to award an accept to a bad answer in spite of community guidance otherwise there is nothing we can do, and changing the question to SYN makes it a nonsense question...

Comment: While TCP is bidirectional, I have to disagree with the "two pipes" statement.  It is one single, bi-directional connection.  Using the terminology of "two pipes" could lead one to believe there are two separate, uni-directional connections.

Comment: @YLearn, I agree with you on the "two pipes" statement, and will edit.  Network engineers understand it's a single pipe; I thought for the OP's rudimentary understanding of TCP that two [logical] pipes would help him understand the nature of the bidirectional connection, and its two halves of a single pipe would be difficult for the OP to grasp.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you say neither side sends an ACK? Each side will ACK any and all data that it receives (in order.) Each side maintains it's own count of data sent and received -- the *sequence number*. This problem "never appears" because it doesn't exist; state is maintained for each direction, so it doesn't matter who sends what when.

If **A** and **B** simultaneously send a packet, say 5 bytes at seq:0, then they will each, *independently*, acknowledge the 5 bytes they've received. The connection is a full-duplex, bidirectional flow. What **A** sends to **B** has no bearing on what **B** sends to **A**.

Comment: I see. I didn't knew it is happen independently, i.e. I thought that a system have one thread that either reading or writing, and as a result, after packets sent, they are both reading, awaiting for acknowledge packet. But @generalnetworkerror already noticed that TCP is bidirectional, and I saw, that probably after a packet with data received, there is another thread which send acknowledge, while the first one continues reading *(or, perhaps, the first one fastly do it, and continue reading)*.